# Building nuxt 3 project missing some plugins stylings

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, vue-toasted, formkit

I have a nuxt 3 project that is working fine on localhost while developing. I use FormKit and vue-toastification and everything is fine on "npm run dev".
But once I run npm run build to build it for deployment. lots of stylings are missing. Mainly those two plugins. the error messages for the forms by FormKit aren't red and not styled. vue-toastifications display with full height and width of the screen as it has no styling.

would I do any extra steps before running npm run build? like building these plugins or something?
this is my nuxt.config.ts file if it might help!

```
// @ts-nocheck
import Icons from "unplugin-icons/vite"

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: ["~/assets/fonts/droidkufi/droidarabickufi.css", "@formkit/themes/genesis"],
    modules: [
        "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss",
        [
            "@pinia/nuxt",
            {
                autoImports: ["defineStore"],
            },
        ],
        "@formkit/nuxt",
    ],
    plugins: ["~/plugins/flowbite.client.ts", "~/plugins/i18n.ts"],
    vite: {
        plugins: [
            Icons({
                autoInstall: true,
            }),
        ],
    },
    runtimeConfig: {
        // secret serverside variables
        public: {
            // baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/",
            // apiBase: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/",
            // homeBase: "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
            baseURL: "https://sju.davidlouis.co/api/",
            apiBase: "https://sju.davidlouis.co/api/",
            homeBase: "https://sju.davidlouis.co",
        },
    },
    vue: {
        compilerOptions: {
            isCustomElement: (tag) => ["datepicker-hijri"].includes(tag),
        },
    },
})
```

I tried to run `npm run dev` back to test if styles are working. and yes they are working fine. the problem starts when I run `npm run build` for production and deployment.

Comment: Do you see any errors in DevTools on the un-styled site, such as files that cannot be found?

Comment: no.. I found further explanation for the problem. generated style file is already loaded but it has an attribute rel="prefetch" not rel="stylesheet".. when i change it manually in inspector styles are applied. So now we sure it's the problem.
but these style files are generated automatically when i run npm run build. so how would i disable the prefetch and make it runs automatically?